# Javascript odd behaviour on mouse scroll up / down classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm hoping a Javascript wiz can help a fellow citizen out with resolving a problem. I've a fairly straight forward function. When I scroll down by 1px I would like to apply a bounceDown class, this will run for 5 seconds and the class will then disappear for future running of the same function.

When I scroll up from that current scroll position I would like the bounceUp effect to apply. However the issue is I think the bounceUp effect only works once you scroll past the original scroll but in addition to this if the previous function is still running on it's 5 second transition then it gets jumpy as it's trying to run two classes at the same time so there almost needs to be a delay applied.

Does anyone think they can help, I'd gratefully appreciate it.

```html
<script>
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({ 

        addTemporaryClass: function(className, duration) {
            var elements = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                elements.removeClass(className);
            }, duration);

            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).addClass(className);
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 1) {
        $(".spanner").addTemporaryClass("BounceDown", 5000);
    }
 
 else if (scroll <= 1) {
        $(".spanner").addTemporaryClass("BounceUp", 5000);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a boolean variable that is 'true' when `addTemporaryClass` is running? So:

```
(function($){

    var classAdded = false; //New

    $.fn.extend({ 

        addTemporaryClass: function(className, duration) {
            classAdded = true; //New
            var elements = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                elements.removeClass(className);
                classAdded = false; //New
            }, duration);

            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).addClass(className);
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 1 /*New*/ && !classAdded /*New*/) {
        $(".spanner").addTemporaryClass("BounceDown", 5000);
    }

    else if (scroll <= 1 /*New*/ && !classAdded /*New*/) {
        $(".spanner").addTemporaryClass("BounceUp", 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked a treat! I have accepted your answer :)